# When a cell is empty I want to show message, otherwise run a process

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void dgvComp_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvComp.Rows[dgvComp.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["EmplId"].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (dgvComp.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "EmplId")
            {

                {

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    string auto = dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmplId"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
                    dt = dataAcc.rtrvData("empl_Name,empl_Id,desg_Name", "dbo.Empldmgrphcs INNER JOIN  dbo.Designation ON dbo.Empldmgrphcs.desg_Id = dbo.Designation.desg_Id ", "empl_EmpId='" + auto + "'");
                    dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvname"].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empID"].Value = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvdesi"].Value = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is what I am using to fill the `DataGridView`, but when a cell is empty I am getting error.

How can I handle a condition for having an empty cell?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Share the error and the line on which it occurs, please.

Comment: There is no row at position 0. error

Comment: That query doesn't seem to return rows. If EmlId is an integer you might want to remove those apostrophes "empl_EmpId=" + auto

Comment: query is when i am entering data no problem ,but when i am giving cell is emty then only its giving error

Answer (score 0):

Display a message box and set:  `e.Cancel = true;`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgvComp_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
   if (dgvComp.Rows[dgvComp.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["EmplId"].ToString() != "")
   {
      if (dgvComp.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "EmplId")
      {
         {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string auto = dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmplId"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            dt = dataAcc.rtrvData("empl_Name,empl_Id,desg_Name", "dbo.Empldmgrphcs INNER JOIN  dbo.Designation ON dbo.Empldmgrphcs.desg_Id = dbo.Designation.desg_Id ", "empl_EmpId='" + auto + "'");

            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvname"].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
               dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["empID"].Value = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
               dgvComp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dgvdesi"].Value = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Validation Fail");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `else` if you're returning after the `if` statement. :)